# Undefined type 'Fromtify\Database\R'

Tags: php, redbean

I'm new to PHP. When working with namespaces, I ran into a problem with RedBeanPHP.
I have php script **"db.php"**:

```
namespace Fromtify\Database {

    require_once('../libs/rb-mysql.php');

    class Contoller
    {
        public function Connect()
        {
            R::setup(
                #My database settings here...
            );

            if (!R::testConnection()) {
                echo 'Cant connect to database';
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My IDE(VSCode) tells me: **"Undefined type 'Fromtify\Database\R"**
How can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Where and how is the `R` class defined?

Comment: You need to import that class. Right under your namespace declaration, add `use R;` If you don't, it will assume that the class you're trying to use is under your current namespace. Also, unless you have multiple namespaces in the same file (which you normally won't have), then you only need to add `namespace Fromtify\Database;` in the top and can skip the `{ }`. Makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: @M.Eriksson it really helped, thanks a lot

Comment: I posted an answer with some more details. If that solved your issue, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use namespaces, PHP will assume that any class you load is under that namespace as well, unless you've imported it.

Example:

```
namespace Foo;

$bar = new Bar;
```

This will assume that `Bar` also is under the namespace `Foo`.

If the class you're using is under another namespace, or not in a namespace at all (the global namespace), you need to tell PHP which class to use by importing it. You do this with the [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
namespace Foo;

use Bar;

$bar = new Bar;
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
namespace Fromtify\Database {
    use R;

    R:setup(...);
    // The rest of your code

}
```

*Side note!*_

Unless you have multiple namespaces in the same file, which you usually don't have, there's not need for the syntax:

```
namespace Foo {
    // your code
}
```

You can simpy do:

```
namespace Foo;

// Your code.
```

...which makes the code a bit cleaner.

You can read more about [defining namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php) and [using namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in the manual